# Error: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e31' en ASP clásico

Tags: asp

Tengo que dar mantenimiento a una pagina que esta en `asp`, la cosa es que revisando unos filtros me dio el siguiente error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e31'
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]@Estado:
/cartulinas/privado/pedidos.asp, line 586
```

Busque en foros pero no he encontrado una respuesta concreta, ¿alguien podría decirme por qué pasa esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Dejo el código asp aquí:

[Codigo Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a98b5285055eaa09555)

PD: la linea 586 en la foto corresponde a la 155 en el enlace de Gist

Comment: Dónde está tú código? Deberías ponerlo en la pregunta.

Comment: lo puse como enlace sorry

Comment: No se trata de poner todo el código. Deberías proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el error. Tienes que facilitar el trabajo a la gente que te intenta ayudar. Además así tienes más posibilidades de ser tu el que encuentre el error y de aprender cosas nuevas.

Comment: Está demorando mucho esa consulta? puede ser por **Timeout** ese error.

Comment: la cosa es que ejecuto el query y no hay problema, pero si ingreso a la pagina de desarrollo y pruebo 2 filtros específicos  salta ese error de timeout

Comment: o sea que cambia la _query_ al cambiar los filtros?

Comment: lo que podrías hacer es con la query que te arroja el error hacer un `explain` en la base de datos para saber porqué se puede estar pasando con tu consulta.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner qué resultado obtienes cuando escribes `qStringSql` por pantalla cuando te da fallo? Así al menos podríamos ver si la consulta es correcta o no

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ese error corresponde a tiemout.

Comment: @Alan Cierto. Y ahora que veo el código mejor, tampoco importaría mucho que compartiera el valor de esa variable porque no es la consulta en sí sino la llamada a un procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Es cierto @AlvaroMontoro. Es un procedimiento.

Comment: @Zieg's acá te falto colocar la foto? "PD: la linea 586 en la foto corresponde a la 155 en el enlace de Gist"

Comment: no @Goerman, el  puso el link al código.

Answer (score 1):

Ese código indica que estás obteniendo un `timeout` por parte de la base de datos. El código de error de OLE DB significa `DB_E_ABORTLIMITREACHED`.

Por lo que se ve en tu código estás llamando a  un procedimiento almacenado, deberías investigar por ese lado que puede estar pasando verificar las consultas que haga el mismo si tienes acceso, haciendo un [Execution Plan](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) y viendo que problemas tienen las consultas.

[Acá hay una lista de errores OLE DB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171852.aspx)

### Ver también:

- [Cómo obtener un `Execution Plan`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/1913893)
- [SHOWPLAN - permisos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178086.aspx)
- [Analizando SQLServer Plan Cache](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1661/analyzing-the-sql-server-plan-cache/)